# Compiling GWT via command line

Tags: gwt, ant, compilation, capistrano

We have an application that we currently deploy using Capistrano. The application make use of php as it's backend and GWT as a frontend.

I have managed to compile the GWT via an Ant file, but would like to replace the Ant file with a custom Capistrano task.

In order for me to to be able to replace it with a Capistrano task, I need to be able to compile the GWT from the command line.

I have been looking around and Google for quite a while, but have no luck. Does any one know if it is possible to compile GWT using only a single command?

Since it is possible to do it via Apache Ant, I believe it should be possible via command line.

Operating system we want to compile on is Linux, Ubuntu to be exact.

Comment: If you can build GWT with an Ant file, shouldn't that be a single command assuming that your build machine has Ant installed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, this is documented at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideCompilerOptions

```
java -cp gwt-dev.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler ...
```